# Event for QMactoolbar in QT for Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I have problem with QT in Mac.
I create QMactoolbar and I want to add textfield ( look line QLineEdit in Windows ), but when I using "connect" for it, I don't see SIGNAL "textChange" (look like textChanged(QString) of QLineEdit in windows). Please help me create SIGNAL for it, or create textfield in Mac ( don't using QLineEdit because it use in Windows, not Mac)

```
QMacToolBar *mactoolbar = new QMacToolBar();

QList<QMacToolBarItem *> list;

QMacToolBarItemEx *item = new QMacToolBarItemEx(); // create item
item->customViewStyle(QMacToolbarItemEx::SearchTexfieldView);

list.append(item);
mactoolbar -> setItems(list);

connect(item,SIGNAL(activated()),this,SLOT(close()));
```

Comment: Why are you not using QLineEdit ? It can be used in both mac and windows... The major advantage of Qt is that is multiplatform so you don't have to write (a lot of) code to make it work on all platforms. Don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: Hehe, thanks for your idea. I used QLineEdit instead QMacToolBarItemEx. But it not like TextBox in Mac.